# How to create a script to launch android emulator

Tags: android, bash, android-emulator, emulation

I would like to have a script to launch my android emulator without opend Eclipse or using a windows shell (commands example :cd C:..\sdh\tools.. etc emulator -avd ) but simply launching a script.

Thanks a lot

Comment: 1) Work out and test the command line you would like to have executed 2) put it in a script

Comment: ok thanks, i know command line but I don't know how to create a script. 
EX: how to create a script to run "CD .. " ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a .bat file?  At a basic level, pretty much just a list of commands one per line.

Comment: A script typically contains *shell commands*.  Try: it wouldn't explode.  Trust me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved creating a .bat file with a simple edit text (Ex NotePad) and I wrote:

CD C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\eclipse\sdk\tools

emulator -avd Emulatore2

I saved it FileName.bat .
I run the bash file  (Ex: Emulator.bat).

All bash commands:
http://ss64.com/nt/